# Using each sql SELECT result, do an UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, subquery

I'm trying to write a sql query that for each result from this query:

```
select * from table2 where job_id = 'job1' and size=0
```

should set job_id to '00' in table1.

So far I've tried:

```
update table1 set job_id = '00' 
where id from ( select * from table2 where job_id = 'job1' and size=0 )
```

I am guessing that there should be something like a for each loop?

Comment: The `update` syntax is quite vendor specific. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 1):

In many databases, you could phrase this with `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
update table1 
set job_id = '00' 
where exists (
    select 1 
    from table2 t2 
    where t2.job_id = 'job1' and t2.size = 0 and t2.id = table1.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a column like `id` in `table1` to be compared to the results of the subquery, you can use the operator `IN`:

```
update table1 
set job_id = '00' 
where id in (select id from table2 where job_id = 'job1' and size = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing like a loop.  Instead, you just use `set` functions.  The closest syntax to what you are trying is:

```
update table1
    set job_id = '00'
    where id in (select t2.id.  -- assuming the comparison column is `id`
                 from table2 t2
                 where t2.job_id = 'job1' and t2.size = 0
                );
```

The `update` itself is -- conceptually -- like a "for" loop.  It is a *set* operation that applies to all rows in the table that meet the conditions in the `where` clause.

I should emphasize the "conceptually".  The `update` does not (necessarily) loop through all the rows one at a time.  Relational databases offer a multitude of algorithms for making queries more efficient (although looping through the rows one-by-one is always an option).